# Something wrong with libpng on biicode?

Tags: biicode

I've been using `libpng` from `biicode` for quite some time now. Just today, I have started receiving this error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'pnglibconf.h': No such file or directory
```

I have noticed on `biicode` (http://www.biicode.com/glenn/png) that the specific file is listed as `_pnglibconf.h`. I don't know if this is a recent change or if it has always been the case. Does someone know if the block has been modified in some way (it is still stable version 0) and if it needs to be corrected or if it can be made to work as it is somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Its fixed now in version 1 (https://www.biicode.com/glenn/png) Try to update your dependency. It was a problem in CMakeLists.txt including a directory where pnglibconf.h is generated from _pnglibconf.h

Comment: Great! I can go back to using that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Biicode's "_pnglibconf.h" should be "pnglibconf.h".  I don't know why there is a leading underscore.  Also it is out of date; it's from libpng-1.5.10 not 1.6.10, according to the comment within it.  Try copying scripts/pnglibconf.h_prebuilt to pnglibconf.h

Comment: You're totally right, file "_pnglibconf.h" should not be there. Its fixed now in version 1 (http://www.biicode.com/glenn/png).
CMakeLists.txt generates "pnglibconf.h" from "scripts/pnglibconf.h_prebuilt".
It was missing an include_directories in CMakeLists.txt that links with generated "pnglibconf.h".